# MailChimp integration error magento 2.3.3

Tags: mailchimp, magento2marketplace

I am trying to configure MailChimp with my Magento 2.3.3. As I enter the API and leave the field a popup appears "Attention" without any error or any other text.

Help me to sort it out.

Comment: Please give more details. Check console and log.

Comment: there is no error in logs

Comment: and also no error found in console